# s4sdk - Cannot connect to NodeJS microservice

Tags: s4sdk

I was in the proccess of extending the tutorial mentioned in Step 9, with a NodeJS micro service. However I am having some strange issue with the comunication to the backend.

The flow I have is an App Router that directs to an HTML5 micro service (static buildpack) and this consumes either a Java or NodeJS microservice. The Java part works fine along with authentication scopes, but for NodeJS I am always getting 404 (not found) error when I call the respective path /node/hello (hello should return a function output from server).

This is the xs-app.json I am using for routing

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "index.html",
  "authenticationMethod": "route",
  "websockets": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "/odata/v4/(.*)",
      "target": "/odata/v4/$1",
      "destination": "business-partner-api"
    },
    {
      "source": "/",
      "target": "/",
      "destination": "business-partner-frontend"
    },
    {
      "source": "/node/(.*)",
      "target": "/$1",
      "destination": "business-partner-node"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is on the /node block the others work fine. I have also noticed another strange issue, is that if I replace the default destination (/) from business-partner-frontend to business-partner-node the app router sucessfully calls the node js server with the authentication being propagated so it appears the issue is somehow related with the xs-app file and not in the destination itself.

I have also unsuccessfully tried to add the port to the destination and adding a staticfile mapping the html5 project but without success.

Anything I might be missing on the node part config?

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your destinations?

Comment: Hi Dennis, the destinations I am using are currently mapped withing the manifest file of the app-router, find it bellow:

Comment: env:
    TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: 'approuter-(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'
    destinations: '[
        {
          "name":"business-partner-api",
          "url" :"https://firstapp-*****.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/",
          "forwardAuthToken": true
        }, {
          "name":"business-partner-frontend",
          "url" :"https://html5_module-*****.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/"
        }, {
          "name":"business-partner-node",
          "url" :"https://nodejs_module-*****.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/",
          "forwardAuthToken": true
        }
      ]'

Comment: I assume you have already tried accessing your node microservice directly?

Comment: With authentication in place I always get the Unauthorized message, however it is also not possible to acess it with this technique : https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/29/oauth-client-grant-types-authorization_code-password but with the Java one it is. The only way I have to actually access it is to actually map it to the "/" path so it can grab the auth and there I see the expected message from the NodeJS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably in the order of your routes, which is important for the routing. The first match of the current path against `source` will determine the route. In your case, the `/` of the second route matches all paths, including `/node/...`.

Reorder your routes so that the node destination comes before the frontend destination.